# Error in models, TypeError: on_delete must be callable

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, linux, django-models

When I run the following command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I have this error:

```py
  File "/home/user/project/myvirt/forum/boards/models.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Topic(models.Model):
  File "/home/user/project/myvirt/forum/boards/models.py", line 12, in Topic
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics', on_delete='cascade')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 801, in __init__
    raise TypeError('on_delete must be callable.')
TypeError: on_delete must be callable.
```

My models.py content is:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics', on_delete='cascade')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='topics', on_delete='cascade')

class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    topic = models.CharField(Topic, related_name='posts', on_delete='cascade')
    created_by = models.CharField(User, related_name='posts', on_delete='cascade')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_by = models.CharField(User, related_name='posts', on_delete='cascade')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

This is an exercise in sample forum and seems to be a problem with `on_delete='cascade'`.

## Update:

I am using Django version 3.

Comment: correct this part, on_delete=models.CASCADE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your model fields you are assigning a string for `on_delete`. (-> `on_delete='cascade')

What you need to do is to assign (as the error tells you) a callable, like `CASCADE`.

Example:

```py
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_relation = models.ForeignKey(
        MyOtherModel,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    ...
```

Furthermore: You are setting `related_name=XYZ` on **all** your fields. This is incorrect, because a related_name can only be assigned to fields which handle relations, like `ForeignKey`.

Also see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

Comment: Thanks now I have this error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'related_name'
`

Comment: @Morteza.J edited this to my answer. The problem (as described) is that you are assigning a related_name to all of your fields. This argument is only available for fields that handle relations, like `ForeignKeyField`, `OneToOneField`, ...

Comment: I got the issue, sorry, I have to rename some `models.CharField` to `models.ForeignKey` :)

Answer (score 1):

The error message `on_delete must be callable` indicates that it should be callable instead of string.

Following the Django official documentation [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey), and here is a example:

```
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        'Manufacturer',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```